# OpenVZ Questions

Tags: openvz

I want to create a brand new node and have a few questions:

OS Templates:
http://wiki.openvz.org/Download/template/precreated

1. Is the "suse" in the first section under "List of templates available at download:template/precreated/ and its mirrors: " a commercial Suse or is it OpenSuse? Does this require a paid license?
2. OpenVZ Web Panel, good or bad? What about SoluvVM and VDS Manager? Which is the best option?

I want the most features for both admin and vps clients.

3. Is Windows 2008 possible on a vps container?
4. Any advice on new vps NODE setup? Security? Optimization?

Any warnings? Such as, what "contributed" os templates to stay away from? I pretty much would like to offer all of them to my clients including:

Centos
Debian
Fedora
Gentoo
OpenSuse
Slackware
SLES
Ubuntu

I'm guessing it doesn't matter if the NODE itself is 64 bit, the containers can be either 32 or 64?

Answer (score 0):

1. The template of Suse is OpenSuse, and does not require a license.
2. OpenVZ Web Panel works great, just 'out of the box'.

And your other questions;

1. No, you can't run Windows 2008 in a VPS. OpenVZ is all LINUX based. Thus, you can only use Linux based Operation Systems (exept Mac). If you want to run Windows in a VPS try VMware.

If the HN (HardwareNode) is 64bit, then you can run a 32bit VPS (not the other way around of course).

Regarding the HN itself. You can choose for Debian, which is quite easy to set-up. The RedHat kernels are a little-bit better maintained, so there CentOS is perhaps better.

Answer (score 0):

For basic things OpenVZ Web Panel might be good, for automation and VPS reselling use SolusVM. For reselling without any cost of control panel, you may try HyperVM (http://www.hypervm-ng.org/).

I would advise hardware raid. I used SW RAID 1 and it died 2 times within like one year or so. I always used 7K RPM HDDs in Raid 1 and performance wise it was not problem for me.

OpenVZ is not compatible with Windows, but you can run Linux remote desktop and use app called "Wine" to run some .exe apps.